# Run command at login - Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, autostart

This has been asked to death, and yet none of the solutions I've found seem to work.

I want to run a command, say `setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps`
, at login. It should only run for me, and not anybody who logs in.

`~/.profile` doesn't work. `~/.xinitrc` doesn't work. `~/.xsession` doesn't work. `~/.config/autostart` doesn't work.

Edit: Ideally, the solution would also be backup-friendly. Config files are easy to copy, and that's one of the great things about Linux systems.

Comment: Try to read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login

Comment: That also doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most certainly, `~/.config/autostart` *does* work if the command works "normally", but you have to be aware of two possible bottlenecks:

1. The launcher in `~/.config/autostart` is a `.desktop` file. To run a complicated command from a `.desktop` file, use the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps"
   ```
2. Some commands break if they run while the desktop is not fully loaded yet. In that case you'd have to add a little break, e.g.:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps"
   ```

Comment: Perfect, getting it to run through bash was the key. Thanks!

Comment: @bfops always nice when things start to work :)